# angular config block not being called

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The code inside my angularjs config block is not getting executed. I have already checked the similar questions on stackoverflow and nothing helped me. I have already checked the 2 possible errors.
1)Missing ng-app in html.

2)Overriding of module.

I am not sure what's going wrong. I can see that the breakpoint is going to this line but it doesn't go inside this block. I also don't see any error on the console. It just silently ignores it. Even if I change $locationProvider to $locationProvider1 , it doesn't give any error.

```
myLittleApp .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
```

**index.html**

```
<html class="no-js" ng-app="littleapp"> 

</html>
```

**app.js**

'use strict';

```
var angular = require('angular');

require('angular-ui-router');

require('angular-ui-bootstrap');

var myLittleApp = angular.module('littleapp', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
   require('./modules/firm').name
]);

myLittleApp .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
console.log('test');
}]);
```

Comment: Just a thought, Are you sure `require('./modules/firm').name` is working correctly? Not sure, but I'd expect .config blocks to evaluate in the order of their dependencies (so that the config block for `littleapp` wouldn't run before the block for `./modules/firm`). What happens if you remove that require?

Comment: I tried that too. no luck. I can see that it's excecuting this code from angularjs library.

Comment: if (isUndefined(event.immediatePropagationStopped)) {
      var originalStopImmediatePropagation = event.stopImmediatePropagation;
      event.stopImmediatePropagation = function() {
        event.immediatePropagationStopped = true;

        if (event.stopPropagation) {
          event.stopPropagation();
        }

        if (originalStopImmediatePropagation) {
          originalStopImmediatePropagation.call(event);
        }
      };

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you provided, Your code seems to have a space between your application variable name and the config function. I removed it. Try it again. I also moved the firmModule outside the app module. One more thing, try following John Papas Style Guide.

Also can you share the .modules/firm code to see how you are exporting the module?

```
var angular = require('angular');

require('angular-ui-router');

require('angular-ui-bootstrap');

var firmModule = require('./modules/firm').name;

var myLittleApp = angular.module('littleapp', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    firmModule 
]);

myLittleApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    console.log('test');
}]);
```

Comment: btinoco - that space got added while copying code here. It doesn't exist in my environment. I have also commented the .modules/firm code. It still doesn't work. Thanks for the pointer to papas style guide.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue on my own. The issue was with ng-app in html file. It should be an attribute of body tag instead of html tag.

**wrong**

```
<html class="no-js" ng-app="littleapp"> 
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Correct**

```
<html class="no-js" > 
<body ng-app="littleapp">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not true, you can use ng-app in the html element too.  Check out this plunkr to see https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:CR2TtS1zz9wFGgsl5z2c?p=preview. Just to know, what is "no-js"?